# Adding members to an existing object

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following object:

```
var obj = {
    fn1: function() {
    }
}
```

how can I dynamically add another member to it, say

```
fn2: function() {}
```

Answer (score 52):

As others have pointed out:

```
obj.fn2 = function(){ ... };
```

Note that if "fn2" is not a valid identifier, you must instead use the 'array' notation for the object:

```
obj["fn2"] = function(){ ... };
obj["!! crazy-names#allowed?!"] = function(){ ... };
```

This is also how you would do it if you had the name of the property stored in a variable:

```
var propName = "fn2";
obj[propName] = function(){ ... };
```

If you want to test if a property exists for an object, you can use the `in` operator:

```
if ("fn2" in obj){ ... }
```

If you want to remove a property from an object, use the `delete` keyword:

```
var o = { a:42 };
console.log( "a" in o ); // true
delete o.a;              // Or delete o["a"]
console.log( "a" in o ); // false
```

To iterate over all properties in an object, use the `in` operator in a for loop. Be sure to `var` the variable so that it isn't global:

```
var o = { a:42, b:17 };
var allPropertyNames  = [];
var allPropertyValues = [];
for (var propName in o){
  // If you don't do this test, propName might be a property inherited
  // by this object, and not a property on the object itself.
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
    allPropertyNames.push(propName);
    allPropertyValues.push(o[propName]);
  }
}
console.log( allPropertyNames );  // [ "a", "z" ]
console.log( allPropertyValues ); // [ 42, 17 ]
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness as well. Another thing worth noting is that if you - like me - want to use object-within-object storage in the same way, you should check for the existence of the propery first and if not, set it with "obj[propName] = {}", and you can then repeat the process for "obj[propName][subPropName]"

Comment: For those who are using flow and are looking for an answer to this, you simply need to add `Object` as your object type.

`const coord:Object = { x:1 }; coord.y = 2;`

If you skip the object type flow seems to seal it to its original shape (here {x:number}, thus `coord.y` produces an error `Property not found in coord).

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple actually:

```
obj.fn2 = function() { }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try out following

```
var obj = {
   fn1: function() {
   } 
}

obj.fn2 = function() {} // this will add another member to existing object
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks!

Hussain.

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = { };

// Adding function by extending the object using dot notation

obj.subtract = function(num1,num2){
    return num1 - num2;
};

console.log(obj.subtract(8,5));//3

//Adding function by extending the object using bracket notation

obj['multiply them'] = function(num1,num2){

    return num1 * num2 ;

};

console.log(obj[' multiply them '](3,3)); // 9
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use prototype for that...

```
obj.prototype.fn2 = function() {
 ....
}
```

or just simply

```
obj.fn2 = function() {
 ....
}
```

Comment: You can't use `prototype` for this. Prototype is only used for objects created using the `new` keyword, and only functions (not object literals) can be used with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Oops, you are right.  prototype won't work w/ object literal.