# How do I add to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding members to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601008/adding-members-to-an-existing-object)

Lets say you have the following object:

```
var object = {
    name: "Shawn"
};
```

I want to know if there is a function so I can add a new "section" to this object.

Like this for example:

`object.add('age',14);`

To turn the above object to:

```
var object = {
    name: "Shawn",
    age: 14
}
```

If you ask, "What have I tried". My answer is: "Nothing, i wouldnt be asking if I knew how to do this". I think it should be possible to do. But I just don't know how I will do it.

I looked at w3schools and don't recall seeing a built in function for this. Thanks you.

Comment: W3Schools is generally [not regarded as a good resource](http://www.w3fools.com/). Instead, I'd recommend the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Comment: To complement icktoofay comments, if you are looking for JavaScript tutorial, Mozilla Developer Network has a [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) that's a very good introduction to JavaScript. You can also explore all documentation available for JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add function properties and methods by using the dot operator `.`:

```
obj.age = 24;
```

This is also equivalent:

```
obj['age'] = 24;
```

Comment: You actually helped me the most with the object['age'] = 14 part. Thats exactly what I was looking for(: Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use array syntax:

```
object['age'] = 14;
```

Or if the property name does not need to be dynamic:

```
object.age = 14;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = {
    name: "Shawn"
};
obj.age=14;
alert(obj.age)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as:

```
var object = {
    name: "Shawn"
};
object.age = 14;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var object = {
    name: "Shawn"
};
object.age = 14;
```