# How to create JavaScript object and fill data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to create a data object dynamically with key-value pairs. In this object, there is also an array named features and also within this array element called geometry one more array coordinates.

In feature array, properties like title and content will add dynamically and also values of coordinates array.

How to add data in coordinates array: "geometery":{"coordinates":[]}.. ?

```
data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Day 1",
        "content": "This is where some people moved to."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -73.7949,
          40.7282,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "The Next Day",
        "content": "This is where some people grooved to."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -74.3838,
          40.9148,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Amazing Event",
        "content": "This is where they went to have fun."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          4.899431,
          52.379189,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "1776",
        "content": "This where they went when the revolution had begun."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -71.3489484,
          42.4603719,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "1776",
        "content": "This where they went when the revolution had begun."

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -71.2272,
          42.4473,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "1984",
        "content": "So they all came here...and disappeared without a trace!"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.118092,
          51.509865,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "12/22/63",
        "content": "Now, this can be quite the scary place."
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -70.2553259,
          43.661471,
          1
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

```
var data = {

    features: []
    };
    for (piece in pieces){

     data.features.push({
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {title: '{piece.title}' , content: '{piece.content}' },
            geometry: {type: "Point"},

   });

  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you don't try anything, it's hard to help because it's unclear what you're having a hard time with. I hope you're not asking someone to write a solution for you.

Comment: This data object is filled static but i want to put contents dynamically in it.

Comment: Creating objects is covered in [Which way is best for creating an object in JavaScript? Is `var` necessary before an object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6843951/215552). Adding members to an existing object is covered in [Adding members to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4601008/215552)... You can [edit] your question to make your question clearer, and to indicate what research you've done and what problems you're having.

Answer (score 1):

What have you already tried and where was your problem?
You could do something like this:

```js
var data = {
    features: []
};

data.features.push({
    type: "Feature"
});
```

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Please refrain from posting code in comments. It should be in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @psren exactly i am doing in this way . now i have add some code in my question.